# how to create a table on bigquery procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I have a query framed to find the tables which is hitting bigquery partitions hard limit(4000).

```
DECLARE dataset_list ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE iter INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE query_tables STRING;

SET dataset_list = (
SELECT
ARRAY_AGG(schema_name)
FROM
project_id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA where schema_name not in ('dp_sample','test_dataset','spark_bigquery_staging'
)
);

WHILE
iter < ARRAY_LENGTH(dataset_list) DO
SET query_tables ="SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,count(PARTITION_ID) as part_tot_cnt from "
|| dataset_list[OFFSET(iter)] || ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS where partition_id is not null group by TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME having part_tot_cnt>3600 " ;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_tables;
SET iter = iter + 1;
END WHILE;
```

I am getting the results in multiple files and it hard to navigate through them ,I am looking for a way i could create a table on top it?. Any better suggestions to rewrite the query would be helpful aswell.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using bigquery for this now

Comment: Did you tried adding ````INSERT Into SELECT <ur-query>```` inside while?

Comment: Actually above query started failing all of a sudden with below error, 

Query error: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS query attempted to read too many tables. Please add more restrictive filters. at [1:1]

Comment: To resolve this query error could you try either  :
(1) adding filter on `table_name` column while querying information schema OR 
(2) Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITION_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` ?

Comment: sure let me check on this suggestions.